# Unable to change keyboard repeat delay

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I was looking for a solution  for a problem, and I needed to know what program  used which shortcuts. The program I found, however, happened to be glitched on Windows 10 and caused it to actually press all possible shortcuts, and it broke the repeat delay when typing.

When you press a button and hold it, it usually waits a second before it starts spamming the characters. This is the thing that doesn't happpen anymore, so when I'm typing, I need to release the button  really fast, otherwise it just puts down the same character multiple times.

Things  I've  tried:

- Disabling everything in the 'Ease of use accessibility'-screen
- Changing the keyboard settings in the configuration  panel, I just don't notice any difference when I change this
- Changing regedit values in 'Keyboard Response' and 'Keyboard' to the same values I have on another PC (HKEY_CURRENT_USER _> Control Panel -> Keyboard Response).  This is what it is set to right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdkw6.png
- Uninstalled the program
- Rebooted multiple times

Here's a small video that might clear up any confusion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1kKOayRTJY

I hope someone  can help  me :(

EDIT: Found a solution, in case someone else has a Ducky Shine 3 with the same issue, try pressing FN + F1, followed by FN + F5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A:** If the keyboard drivers have become corrupted, you can delete them and allow Windows to reinstall them.

1. Open the Device Manager control panel. You can get to it easily by pressing the Windows key and pasting in "device manager" (in case it is too frustrating typing it in).
2. Open the "Keyboards" section.
3. For each keyboard device shown (there may be only one), double-click it, choose the "Driver" tab and click "Uninstall".
4. Restart Windows.

It is possible that you have a keyboard which needs the manufacturer's driver installed for extra functionality. If so, check that the keyboard now works normally and then install that driver.

**B:** Your keyboard may have its own setting for repeat delay which could work independently of the OS and you may have inadvertently set it to zero. Check your keyboard documentation on how to set it to the desired value.

Comment: Just tried removing, rebooting and then reinstalling the keyboard drivers, but I'm still having the same issue (even without reinstalling  the drivers). :(

Comment: Oh wow... Thank you so much! It was actually keyboard related, the shortcut program must've pressed a shortcut on my keyboard that removed all delay. I didn't even know that existed. I'll mark your answer as a solution, since it did put me in the right direction.